# Output claims Heap was modified after freed, but no addition to the Heap

Tags: c++

As the title claims, I am getting an output of:

```
The thread 0x1a34 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1f94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'SecondPersonShooter.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'
The thread 0xbf8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1dbc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
HEAP[SecondPersonShooter.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 48d0e10 modified at 48db40c after it was freed
SecondPersonShooter.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

But I don't allocate anything where I suspect it to be. I just have pointers to memory, nothing dynamically allocated.

Code:

```
    node* currentNode = nullptr;
    node* targetNode = nullptr;

    std::vector<node*> path;

    int valueOrigin = 0;
    int valueTarget = 0;

    float oldDistanceOrigin = 1000.f;  // arbitrary numbers, just so theres a base point for distances
    float oldDistanceTarget = 1000.f;
    for (int i = 0; i < allNodes.size(); i++)
        {
            float distance = sqrt(std::pow(pos.x - allNodes[i].position.x, 2) + std::pow(pos.y - allNodes[i].position.y, 2));

            if (distance < oldDistanceOrigin)
                {
                    oldDistanceOrigin = distance;
                    valueOrigin = i;
                }

            distance = sqrt(std::pow(targetPos.x - allNodes[i].position.x, 2) + std::pow(targetPos.y - allNodes[i].position.y, 2));

            if (distance < oldDistanceTarget)
                {
                    oldDistanceTarget = distance;
                    valueTarget = i;
                }
        }


    bool pathFound = false;

    currentNode = &allNodes[valueOrigin];
    currentNode->explored = true;

    targetNode = &allNodes[valueTarget];

    while (!pathFound)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < currentNode->neighbors.size(); j++)
                {
                    currentNode->explored = false;

                    currentNode->neighbors[j]->gCost = currentNode->gCost + 10;

                    currentNode->neighbors[j]->hCost = ( targetPos.x - pos.x ) / 64;                           // 64 is the size of a node
                    currentNode->neighbors[j]->hCost += ( targetPos.y - pos.y ) / 64;
                    currentNode->neighbors[j]->hCost *= 10;

                    if (currentNode->neighbors[j]->hCost < 0)
                        currentNode->neighbors[j]->hCost *= -1;

                    currentNode->neighbors[j]->fCost = currentNode->neighbors[j]->gCost + currentNode->neighbors[j]->hCost;
                }

            node* selection = currentNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < currentNode->neighbors.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (currentNode->neighbors[i]->fCost < selection->fCost)
                        {
                            selection = currentNode->neighbors[i];
                        }
                }

            if (selection != targetNode)
                {
                    currentNode = selection;
                    path.push_back(currentNode);
                }
            else
                {
                    pathFound = true;
                }  
       }

    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> pathPoints;

    for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++)
        {
            pathPoints.push_back(path[i]->position);
            path[i] = nullptr;
        }   

    cleanup();

    path.clear();

    currentNode = nullptr;
    targetNode = nullptr;
    return pathPoints;
```

Node:

```
struct node
{
    sf::Vector2f position;

    std::vector<node*> neighbors;

    bool explored;

    int gCost;
    int hCost;
    int fCost;
};
```

Sorry for such a large block, but I suspect this isn't the actual culprit. However, commenting out the code will cause the program to run. So I have no idea. 
Sorry if this is a simple question, but I have spent too long trying to debug this

Thanks for your time!

**Edit 1:**

I found out that once I get past the constructor (where all data for neighbors is fine before), once I get into the function posted all data will be garbage. 
Like this:
 Data At Constructor:

```
position= x=1664.00000 y=1920.00000
```

Data After Constructor:

```
position = x=-1.58839967e+038 y=-1.58839967e+038
```

This number is the same for all neighbor-pointer-nodes. Would there be any particular reason why the pointer would suddenly go "bad"?

Comment: "nothing dynamically allocated" simply isn't true when you use objects like `std::vector`.

Comment: And 'modified after free()’ isn't confined to further allocations. You have a wild pointer that has corrupted the heap via a store.

Comment: Try to make some validity checks like `index < vector.size()` and the like. Sometimes, undefined behaviour just compiles and fails silently.

Comment: Kaz - Yeah, I feel dumb for forgetting what vectors do best                       And EJP - How would I go about finding that?

Comment: When the debugger hits the breakpoint with the corrupt heap, examine the memory location that was written to (48db40c in your example) in the memory window to see what was written there.  Sometimes that's enough to recognize where the write comes from.

Comment: Try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Usually, you will either end up with something to post, or discover the problem while doing so

Comment: M.M Yeah, I tried doing that. But any way I tried to get it to break, it was fine. I will try and make one now that I explored the issue more

Answer (score 1):

If `allNodes` is empty, you will corrupt your heap pretty easily:

`currentNode = &allNodes[valueOrigin]; // valueOrigin will be 0 for that case
currentNode->explored = true; // here you will be touching heap memory (where the vector element would have been) where no element actually lies`

Comment: I think my edit shows that this is the case, somewhat. But not with current node.